# Installing a WordPress blog in subfolder with CodeIgniter

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, codeigniter

I have a website built in CI with VirtualHost set to `/var/www/default/html/`. This is where the `index.php` file of CodeIgniter lies as well, whereas the main installation of CodeIgniter is in `/var/www/default/`. It works flawlessly but I have to set up a WordPress blog in `/blog` directory (It has to be in `/var/www/` path. The problem is, I have another `blog.mysite.com` declaration in `/etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf` which goes something like

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName blog.mysite.com
    ServerAdmin admin@mysite.com

    DocumentRoot /var/www/blog/
    <Directory /var/www/blog/>
            Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
            AllowOverride All
            Order allow,deny
            allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

How do I configure `.htaccess` so that I can access the blog using `mysite.com/blog`?

TIA.